# Get sql data using search box in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

What I want to do is using search box to find data in WordPress database and display it in a page,using contact form 7. I upload data in a wp database. I use some PHP code to display data in a page and it works, but I don't know how to do it using a search box.

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;        
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM it_testtable");     
    echo "ID"."  "."Name"."<br><br>";
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        echo $row->id."  ".$row->name."<br>";    
    }        
?>
```

I want when I enter the an id I get names. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: how about referring to this ?
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165478/creating-a-search-form-for-custom-fields

Comment: yes,i did that but i couldn't find the sql database,please can you tell me about how is it connect to wp database..

Comment: is that row consist of ID and name or anything else?

Comment: no,only ID and Name,

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1** Add the following to your `Header.php` file

```
<div class="header-search"><?php get_search_form();?></div>
```

**Step 2** Add the following to your `Style.css` file

```
.header-search{display:none}
@media screen and (min-width:600px){
    .header-search{
        display:block;
        float:right;
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-right:3px;
    }
}
```

**Show search query in search box**
If you have just performed a search, you can show the last query in the search box:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**Show search query in results page**
You can display the search string on search result pages

```
<p>You searched for "<?php echo esc_html( get_search_query( false ) ); ?> ". Here are the results:</p>
```

for reference: [About search box query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_search_query)

- You can go either this or other option,because there is only `name`
  and `ID` in your row

```
$mylink = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->links} WHERE link_id
   = 10" );
```

- Else if you want to show it generically,

```
$fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results(
  "SELECT link_ID,name FROM {$wpdb->links} WHERE link_ID = 5"
);
foreach ( $fivesdrafts as $fivesdraft ) 
{
  echo $fivesdraft->name;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response,but i need actually get the data using search box.my wp data base have two table value ,name and Id and when search the id the name want to automatically display ..

Comment: @nuwansiriwardhana I edited the answer, just check it